# amabri metrics collector error

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We have 5 node hortonworks cluster with ambari monitors installed in all nodes and metrics collector installed in master node.

I am getting Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to 0.0.0.0:6188

PFA for error.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85rPUe3-QPXbXJSRzJmdUwwQU0/view?usp=sharing

I followed the below document and tried removing the service and added it.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Moving+Metrics+Collector+to+a+new+host

First of all, I am not able to find the origin of the error. Please share your experience if you ever faced this problem.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: no..I tried out few things..but I couldn't find any solution on this.

Comment: @VinayKumar Can you check the security rule of your machine ? It allows connection to your port. Check by doing telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes that port is already being use by another process when we try to move collector to new host with 'Curl' commands specified on  apache wiki.

Istead of doing using this you can leverage the feature which Ambari provides from it's GUI to move components from one host to another host .

[image]

'Move Master Wizard'

[image]

Follow the steps stated at Move Master Wizard , Ambari will take care rest of things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by killing the process running in that port and restart the service. You can also do a manual reboot of the machine to fix this issue.